# Разница между Collections.sort() и сортировкой стримом

Tags: java

Я пишу программу, которая выстраивает пирамиду из отсортированных чисел и возвращает двумерный массив.

```
public int[][] buildPyramid(List<Integer> inputNumbers) {
...
}
```

У меня не проходил данный юнит-тест:

```
@Test(expected = CannotBuildPyramidException.class) // класс не содержит никакой логики, только наследуется от RuntimeException
    public void buildPyramid8() {
        List<Integer> input = Collections.nCopies(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 0);
        // run
        int[][] pyramid = pyramidBuilder.buildPyramid(input);
        // assert (exception)
    }
```

Если отсортировать коллекцию данным методом,

`Collections.sort(inputNumbers);`

то вылезает ошибка

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.alex.demo.tasks.pyramid.CannotBuildPyramidException> but was<java.lang.OutOfMemoryError>
```

При этом, если использовать такой формат

```
    List<Integer> sorted = inputNumbers.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

то тест проходит без ошибок. Почему?

Comment: Эм.. А только меня смущает попытка сортировать readonly-коллекцию?

Comment: ну, такой юнит-тест в задании

Comment: Возможно, `sorted` проверяет, что коллекция уже отсортирована, а `sort` пытается делать с неё копию, на которую не хватает памяти. Впрочем, как `sorted` может обойтись без копирования коллекции хотя бы под результат, я не понимаю.

Comment: Странно. Вообще должна быть ошибка и в одном и во втором случае. В первом варианте из-за `Requested array size exceeds VM limit`(потому что  Integer.MAX_VALUE-2). А во втором из-за `Stream size exceeds max array size`(потому что Nodes.MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8). Но даже если уменьшить размер - всё равно придется поднимать java heap. Иначе получите `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. У вас реально такие большие данные возможны?

Comment: сомневаюсь, однако в задании такой юнит тест и его нельзя изменять

Comment: со стримами IllegalArgumentException: Stream size exceeds max array size. Как это у вас тест проходит без ошибок ?